# How to mock SecretClient when it doesn't have an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

If I understand correctly, the [SecretClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.secretclient?view=azure-dotnet) from Azure.Security.KeyVault.Certificates.nupkg is meant to replace [KeyVaultClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclient?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) from Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.nupkg but it doesn't have an interface which makes it hard to mock using NSubstitute.

Working with KeyVaultClient was easy as I could simply do: `Substitute.For<IKeyVaultClient>();`

What is the guidance here? I don't want to have to create my own unit testable wrappers or use a different mocking framework.

EDIT I was able to do this:

```
var secretClient = Substitute.For<SecretClient>();
var page = Page<SecretProperties>.FromValues(new[] { new SecretProperties("SecretName") }, "continuationToken", null);
var pages = new List<Page<SecretProperties>> { page };
secretClient.GetPropertiesOfSecrets().Returns(Pageable<SecretProperties>.FromPages(pages));
secretClient.GetPropertiesOfSecrets().Dump();
secretClient.Received(1).GetPropertiesOfSecrets();
```

Comment: There has been an alarming trend as of late by the Azure SDK team to be resistant to implementing interfaces on their classes.  I don't know why they insist on it, but it is making things very difficult for the rest of us.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but could you use configuration (that can read from KV) instead of reading secrets yourself?

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell that actually works! Unfortunately mocking the Pageables is a pain..